# Automatically update html table

Tags: jquery, html

I have an simple HTML table which I want to let do the following with the help of JQuery;

1. Make it so when I add an date from the future, jQuery makes the date go green.
2. When it's a past date, jQuery makes the date go red.

How do I make jQuery do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not in pure HTML, no. You need either Javascript or perhaps some server-side language involved here.

Comment: So it is possible, but how?

Comment: Again, there are several options. Do you understand anything about JavaScript or other languages? We can’t supply a solution fitting your situation if we know nothing about your situation.

Comment: No, I do not have any experience with those languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with HTML. You have a lot of other options, PHP, .NET, Javascript, etc.
My advice, look into jQuery. http://jquery.com/

I am not giving you the full solution here, but start with jQuery and go on from there. When you have questions about jQuery, ask them in another question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Will do, thank you!

Comment: Do not expect us to create code for you. Try to figure it out yourself and when you come accross any problems, create a NEW question.